# SharePoint View

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, data-view-web-part, view

In below print screen I want to create view only for blue rows when user will open the list for all Purchase No (For Example 11, 12, 13,14 etc) which have all information in single row. For other row same Purchase No which have less information I want to hide inside the Original Purchase No (which have all information) so if user want he can see other entry also.

Please find the print screen below for more clarity. Here I want to create view which shows only blue highlighted columns. Please advice.
[image]

Comment: Try grouping it by Purchase No. You will get all the records of a particular Purchase No. in a group but not exactly what you want..

Comment: You can create new view and add filters to contain only those items where all columns are not empty.

Comment: Thanks Ateet, Can you provide how to write condition for empty column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its work supper. Just attaching the print screen above so may be it will helpful to others if someone need help on this. Thanks.

[image]